# What should I set for origin domain name when using Cloudfront, EB and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to set up CloudFront but getting stuck on the first field **origin domain name**

Currently Im using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my webservice as an **Application**, and the EB url is mapped to a Route 53 domain, the customer accesses the webservice via the Route 53 domain.

With EB one **Application** can have multiple **environments**, and each **environment** has a **load-balancer**. I usually have just one environment but when I want to deploy a new version of the application I create a new environment. Then once that is ready I use **Swap URLs** so that the new environment is the one pointed to my the Route53 domain, and then I delete the old environment. This approach ensures no down-time.

Now with CloudFront the list of values it provides are my S3 containers (not what I want) and the Load-Balancer for any currently running environments. Bu this is not what I want either because if I point it at a load-balancer when I have a new version the environment that load-balancer works for will be terminated

Is it not possible to set it to the Application/Route 53 Domain name so I can deploy new version of my application without breaking anything on CloudFront.

Comment: Turns out that although it is not listed I can indeed just set it the CNAME Ive set in Route53, and it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that although it is not listed I can indeed just set it the CNAME Ive set in Route53, and it works

Comment: I have writen elasticbeanstalk environment-name as origin domain name. Then it worked. Thanks